# LaTeX producing black background with transparent png

Tags: graphics, png

I am trying to use png images that are transparent. This is an example of my `LaTeX` file (I am intentionally putting the images on top of themselves):

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}    
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{picture}(0,0)

\put(0,-350){\fbox{\includegraphics[height=4in]{baseimage.png}}}        
\put(0,-350){\fbox{\includegraphics[height=4in]{overlay.png  }}}    

\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

However, the top image looks like this:

[image]

The actual image just has a colored line, and no background. I've searched thoroughly online to find whether this any reason for this, and cannot find one.

The top of my log file says that my `LaTeX` version is the following:

```
This is pdfeTeX, Version 3.141592-1.21a-2.2 (Web2C 7.5.4) (format=pdflatex 2012.8.30)
```

and I cannot spot any errors in the log file.

I've put one of the png files that I am using [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/169746/image.png).

Comment: I don't have any problems with your graphic. I see no black background and can put e.g. text "behind" the graphic. But my pdftex is much newer than yours: ` Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)`.

Comment: Thank you for testing it out. It sounds like I should upgrade pdftex (I had hesitated as it is on a server but trying to do it now).

Comment: Yes, upgrading seemed to fix this problem. Not sure if I should delete my question or not.

Comment: @celenius: No point in deleting the question. It may help others that run into a similar issue in the future.

Comment: Transparency support for PNGs was added in pdfTeX 1.30.0.

Comment: @schroeder Running this code using both TL 2014 pdfTeX 1.40.15 and a current (TL 2015) pdfTeX 1.40.16 doesn't reproduce the problem.  Are you getting the same result with the linked overlay `.png` or with one of your own?

Comment: Terribly sorry, the problem is with the `createspace` package and not with pdfTeX. I'll ping the createspace folks.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use a newer version of pdfTeX, e.g. by installing the latest TeXLive or MikTeX.