# Createspace package prints transparent layers in pngs as black

Tags: graphics, pdftex, png

This problem is almost identical to [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79906/latex-producing-black-background-with-transparent-png), but my issue is limited to the [createspace](https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace) package.

The problem is reproducible with this code, run with pdfTeX:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[size=novel,bleed]{createspace}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.jpg}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{sample}
\end{document}
```

The pngs render fine when I comment out the createspace line.

Since the [Github repo for createspace](https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace) hasn't been touched in 4 years, is there anything in the sty file that I should be looking for to correct this behaviour? Is there something else I could try?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the createspace package uses PDF/X-1a, [which does not handle transparent pngs well](https://github.com/aginiewicz/createspace/issues/5). The package would need to use PDF/X-4 in order to handle transparencies. The solution is to edit or convert the pngs.